# Does Java allow use of an instance of the current class in its definition?

Tags: java, instance

Does Java allow the use of an instance of the current class in its definition?

Example:

```
public class Component
{
    Component()
    {
       // some code 
    }

    public void method()
    {
        Component comp=new Component();
        // some code
    }
 }
```

I know that it does not result in compile-time errors. I find the self-reference a bit confusing though. Does it mean that Java's semantics allows cyclic definition of classes?

Comment: Recursive data structures are typical examples of such a usage. A tree would be build from nodes which contain nodes of the same type. Note that this is neither self-reference nor cyclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you thought about something like this...
Running this leads to

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
public class AClass {

    private AClass aClass;

    public AClass() {
        this.aClass = new AClass();
        this.aClass.printHello();
    }

    private void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new AClass();
    }
}
```

I've not needed recursive code like this. But i think there could be some use cases.
It is important to have an abort criteria to prevent endless loop and the StackOverflowError.

To answer your question, i would say Java allows cylic instantiation.

Comment: I think you're right in how self-reference in the constructor can be called cyclic, not the reference in the method. Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legal to use / create instance of the same type on the defining class, there is no cyclic definition added.

Compilers usually do a first pass examining all the methods on a class, the actual method implementation code generation is done later once the compiler knows about all the methods available on all the clases.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a cyclic definition.

Cyclic definition is when two or more classes reference each other in a cyclic manner.
But even that would compile, though may lead to execution problems.

It is rather a "use ahead" definition, this is how I would call it.

You define a class and in its method you use a reference to the same class.

It is a bit contradictory - before you use a class you should completely define it.
A method of a class is a part of its definition.
Where as in a method you reference a class instance as if the class was already defined.

I agree it is confusing, but Java let you do this.

Think of a singleton.

Often there is a static method that returns the class instance. 
The same problem.